# Error code 101 --no-packager with React Native toolkit in Visual Studio Code

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code

I am new to React Native and trying to get my first React application to run on Android Emulator. I am getting this error message when running the debugger:

> Could not debug. Error while executing command
> 'c:\Users...\weather4\node_modules.bin\react-native.cmd run-android
> --no-packager': Error while executing command 'c:\Users...\weather4\node_modules.bin\react-native.cmd run-android
> --no-packager' (error code 101)

**launch.json**

```
{

"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Debug Android",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "android"
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach to packager",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "attach"
    },
    
   
]
}
```

**settings.json**

```
{
"dart.flutterSdkPath": "C:\\src\\flutter",
"react-native.packager.port": 19001
}
```

**Path** env variable

```
C:\Users\...\.vscode\extensions\msjsdiag.vscode-react-native-0.16.0\src\common
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar errors and found this fix:

1. Uninstall Flutter (and Dart) extensions from Visual Studio Code.
2. Close Visual Studio Code, delete the `.vscode` folder and open Visual Studio Code again.
3. Configure the "Run and debug" panel again so you can run the app.